# How to convert complex tuples into JSON structure

Tags: python, json

Currently, I have two (large) lists like these:

```
labels = ['name1', 'name2', 'name3', 'name4', ...]
values = [5, 8, 6, 7, ...]
```

And I need to create a JSON output like this, using a loop:

```
[{"value": 5, "label": "name1"}, {"value": 8, "label": "name2"}, {"value": 6, "label": "name3"}, {"value": 7, "label": "name4"}, ...]
```

I tried several examples of code around Internet, i.e.:

```
dictionary = [dict(zip(labels, values))]
data = json.dumps(values)
print data
```

But working with tuples seems to be a little harder. And the requirement of constant labels like "value" makes it more confuse for me.

Any suggestion?

Comment: `Any suggestion?` Here's one: Give this a shot yourself and come back if you run into trouble.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a temporary list of dictionaries and pass it to `json.dumps()`. `izip_longest()` is used to gracefully handle the case where the two lists aren't the same size.

```
import json

try:
    from itertools import izip_longest
except ImportError:    # Python 3
    from itertools import zip_longest as izip_longest

labels = ['name1', 'name2', 'name3', 'name4']
values = [5, 8, 6, 7]

temp = [{'value': value, 'label': label}
            for label, value in izip_longest(labels, values, fillvalue='')]

print(json.dumps(temp))
```

Output:

```
[{"value": 5, "label": "name1"}, {"value": 8, "label": "name2"}, {"value": 6, "label": "name3"}, {"value": 7, "label": "name4"}]
```

Answer (score -1):

How about:

```
print [{'value':a, 'label':b} for (a, b) in zip(values, labels)]
```

Comment: It worked perfect. I wonder how the JSON api was unnecessary at all to solve this problem! :O